# Unable to create e4 application on eclipse luna

Tags: eclipse

```
    i am using eclipse Luna. I have installed e4 tools
    When i tried to create e4 project as File -> New -> Other… -> Eclipse 4 Application Project. Following error occurs:
```

Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Plug-in Manifest Builder' on project 'testing'.
    java.lang.NullPointerException What is the reason?

Comment: I don't know what is causing the error but you would do well to move to Eclipse Mars as the e4 tools are improved in that release.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message